# vim /etc/ansbile/ansible.cfg opens an empty file instead of the default ansible.cfg

Tags: ansible

While following a training, I ran `vim /etc/ansbile/ansible.cfg` on my Mac.

In the training video, this command loads a default ansible configuration file while on my Mac it came back with a blank page.

How can I get a default config file to start editing it?

Comment: Related question: https://superuser.com/questions/975319/can-t-find-the-config-file-in-etc-ansible-on-mac-os-x

It came back blank because the file didn't existed before, as the configuration path seems to be different on MacOS than on Linux.

Comment: There is no default ansible configuration file by default (and yes I'm fully aware this sentence can be misleading so please read it twice :)). You can easily create an `ansible.cfg` file containing commented out default values of all known parameters and store it wherever you like (e.g. system wide, user home, project level...) with the following command: `ansible-config init --disabled -f ini > /tmp/ansible.cfg`

Comment: @Zeitounator, perhaps your comment should be in the answers section. Your comment covered the reason and solution. would be helpful for future readers.

Comment: @P.... That was not my first impression but I might be wrong. So here we go.

Answer (score 4):

There is no default ansible configuration file by default. In other words, ansible does not create any system wide configuration file at install and will use default values for all parameters if run without any existing configuration file (system wide, user home, project level...)

Since you are trying to edit a file which does not exist, vim starts with an empty buffer to create a new file.

You can easily create an `ansible.cfg` file containing commented out default values of all known parameters and store it wherever you like with the following command:

```
ansible-config init --disabled -f ini > /tmp/ansible.cfg
```